# How RequestMapping works in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

spring-servlet.xml

```
 <bean id="viewResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
          <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />  
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />  
     </bean>
```

controller class

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/admissionForm.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView getAdmissionForm() {

            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("AdmissionForm");

            return model;
        }
        @RequestMapping(value="/admissionForm.jsp", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView getAdmissionForm2() {

            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("AdmissionForm");

            return model;
        }
        @RequestMapping(value="/admissionForm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView getAdmissionForm3() {

            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("AdmissionForm");

            return model;
        }
```

web.xml

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

whenever i am accessing the url through /admissionForm.html and /admissionForm
i am getting response in webpage but when i access through /admissionForm.jsp i am getting 404 page not found ,my question is what's the reason for this and what i could do to make this work?

Comment: Post your `web.xml`, the answer may be there.

Comment: @Tunaki there you go

Answer (score 2):

change in web.xml file

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I am not sure if its for example or your real code but it the mehods are the same you can write

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/admissionForm","/admissionForm.htm","/admissionForm.html"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

For your issue, you can try to change your web.xml to

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

so it will recognize the `jsp` extension